Does the teleological approach to philosophy of history build a foundation for simulation theory?
Christopher Lloyd puts forward four "general concepts of causation" used in history:
the "metaphysical idealist concept", which asserts that the phenomena of the universe are products of or emanations from an omnipotent being or such final cause;
the "empiricist (or Humean) regularity concept", which is based on the idea of causation being a matter of constant conjunctions of events;

the "functional/teleological/consequential concept", which is goal-directed, so that goals are causes;

the "realist, structurist and dispositional approach", which sees relational structures and internal dispositions as the causes of phenomena
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_history#:~:text=Philosophy%20of%20history%20is%20the,now%20referred%20to%20as%20analytic.
I think that studding the dynamics of human history is the most productive path to understanding where we came from and where we are going to.
The Simulation Theory is a rather modern phenomenon, but I would like to find its roots in traditional philosophy, in particular, goal-directed concept.

Philosophy of History has a difficult history. On one hand, if you accept that the History of humanity has a goal, then it is straight forward to figure out what this goal is, together with understanding of the World. But then, you would have to believe in intelligent design. So, we prefer the other hand.

"if you accept that the History of humanity has a goal, then it is straight forward to figure out what this goal is" - so what would it be in that case?

@TKoL - Astronomers just need to see a tiny bit of a space body's trajectory to figure out its path.

So the goal of humanity is to figure out the trajectory of a body in space?

It is difficult for the human brain to account for billions of events in human history. But it is not difficult at all for a computer model. If an intuitive rationalization of human history was rejected by most scholars as lacking scientific evidence, then computer models could change this view.

The core of your question seems to be:-

The Simulation Theory is a rather modern phenomenon, but I would like to find its roots in traditional philosophy, in particular, goal-directed concept.

If you are asking for a history of the simulation hypothesis in philosophy on the basis of a goal-directed concept of history, I'm afraid I am not in a position to provide one. But there is a certain amount of narrative that can be provided.
The hypothesis can been seen as a version of Descartes' sceptical method in his Meditations, with echoes in Berkeley's idealism. (Descartes rejects the idea that our perceptions are fed to us either by God or by an "evil demon". Berkeley argues that they are fed to us by God). It is hard to reject the suggestion that there is a connection, although Nick Bostrom, the originator of the hypothesis has not, as far as I know, acknowledged or denied one. Nick Bostrom published his argument in 2001/2003 - See Nick Bostrom's Simulation Argument webpage
But there are far more ancient ideas that are similar. In philosophy, the best known of these is Plato's Cave in his Republic. But this is presented as an analogy, rather than a truth. For details of other similar ideas that are not usually regarded as philosophical, see Wikipedia - Simulation hypothesis.
One could speculate about a final cause related to the hypothesis, but I don't think there's any serious evidence that there is one. On the other hand, since a simulation presupposes a simulator, the hypothesis could provide a basis for an intelligent designer of human history.
In your comment you say:-

... if you accept that the History of humanity has a goal, then .... you would have to believe in intelligent design.

That may be so. But you do not have to believe in an intelligent (or unintelligent) designer.
In our time, both Hegel and Marx argued that history is the unfolding of an impersonal process with an end result (perhaps a destiny, rather than a purpose). See Wikipedia - Marxist historiography and SEP - Hegel's philosophy of history
Evolutionary theory suggests that everything that we do must be affected by the process that drives evolution - survival and reproduction. I don't know that anyone has actually tried to write history from that point of view. Arguably, its processes are so slow that they are unlikely to show up in the time-scale that history considers.
You also say (in your question):-

I think that stud(y)ing the dynamics of human history is the most productive path to understanding where we came from and where we are going to.

Most historians are very sceptical of attempts to predict the future on the basis of the past. They do not see history as a science, or having the ambitions of a science, but as a narrative, which is a different form of understanding. For more on this, see SEP - Philosophy of History. So you may find it more productive to look at sociology and economics. On the other hand, many people accept that even if "history doesn't repeat itself, it rhymes".

Ludwig V - I am a bit humbled by your detailed review. It confirms my uneducated hunch that both traditional philosophy and Abrahamic religions were reluctant to see human history as an intelligent act with milestones and final purpose. In particular, I agree with your hypothesis: "They do not see history as a science, or having the ambitions of a science"

+1 for Descartes' skepticism. One could follow that with Kant's reasoning that there is no thing-in-itself, and that we only see our own mental projection onto phenomena. So even if every grain of sand is a Matrix world it just looks like sand unless you look very closely.

I appreciate your comment. But there's no great trick to it. It's no more than the fact that a long-time inhabitant of a town can tell a visitor about what you can find and where to find it. Stick around and join in when you can, and you'll see.

But you've misunderstood something. All the Abrahamic religions see human life (and history) as having a final purpose - the end of the world and the Messiah. Aristotle thought that human beings, like everything else, had a final purpose - how far others agreed with him, I don't know. Until around 17th centure CE, philosophy in Western Europe accepted Christianity. Things began to change after that. My final paragraph was about modern historians.

@ChisDegnen Thanks. You are quite right. But then I felt the answer would develop into a survey of the whole history of philosophy and that seemed excessive.

@LudwigV - "a final purpose - the end of the world" - This is not philosophy or scientific thinking. This represents a lack of ideas. "I don't know what will happen. Let's kill everyone, by default."

It is possible now to load all newspapers for the last 300 years (as a big data) and let AI search for patterns.

I'm sure it would find many. But finding a pattern doesn't explain why it holds. Until you've identified the intelligent designer, there are unintelligent processes like evolution that can produce the same or similar results as intelligent design. That's the default. Thanks for the tick

@LudwigV - It is a process. When you are 30, you don't believe much in intelligent design. But by the time you are 60, the evidence in your personal life starts to accumulate and points to the practical impossibility of randomness and free choice. But then again, it is your personal life. You can write a book about it, but you cannot submit a peer-reviewed paper.
